# How do I configure Android minify to allow Flurry?

Tags: android

Now that proguard is deprecated and we have the "minify" app operation as the suggested replacement instead, I've run into the old problem (again) of Flurry breaking.  In the past an exclusion could be added to the proguard.cfg file for the Flurry libraries.  However, I've been unable to find the appropriate configuration file to do the same for the minify system.

How do I configure the current (1.0RC2) version of Android Studio/Minify to exclude the Flurry libraries (com.flurry.**)?

**edit**

proguard.cfg has the following for Flurry support:

```
-keep class com.flurry.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.flurry.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that has changed (so far) is the name of the gradle option (from `runProguard` to `minifyEnabled`) - everything else is the same. This means you can continue to pass your own proguard configuration files via the `proguardFile` option to exclude Flurry libraries as before.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but I replaced runProguard true with setMinifyEnabled(true) while keeping proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg' in place and it doesn't work.  The proguard lines worked in 0.85 just before I did the 1.0RC2 upgrade.  What else might I be missing here?

Comment: I thought I had it working, but it was just slow to throw errors on a run.  I'm putting my Flurry section of proguard.cfg up into the question.